# Calculate Total Onclick Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning Javascript and am still very new to the language.
In my HTML code I have two lists.
In the first select list you select the product you want
In the second you  select the amount of product you require.

I have attempted to write a javascript code which does the following:

- Get the product value and assign it to a variable
- Get the nr of product and assign it to a variable
- Multiply the product value with the number of product
- When the user clicks submit display an alert box with the total

However my code is not working when the user click the submit button I get the message NaN instead of the result of the total amount variable
Please can you have a look at my code and tell me what am I doing wrong

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc()
{
   var total;
   var fruitOrVeg;
   var nrOfFruit;

   course = document.getElementsByName("fruitOrVeg.course.value")
   nrOfFruit = document.getElementsByName("nrOfFruit")

   total = fruitOrVeg * nrOfFruit;

   window.alert(total)
}
</script>
```

Comment: use the eval function. The eval() function evaluates or executes an argument.

Comment: Don't use eval. Eval is bad.

Comment: Can you show us your Html as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the values as strings (rather than numbers), and you weren't using "fruitOrVeg". Also (noticed later/ new comments) you are using names when you should really use ID's for elements you want javascript to get data from directly and specifically, and then update your js accordingly.  Try this:

```
function calc() {
    var fruitOrVeg = Number(document.getElementsById("fruitOrVeg").value);
    var nrOfFruit = Number(document.getElementsById("nrOfFruit").value);

    var total = fruitOrVeg * nrOfFruit;

    window.alert(total)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Like sarcastic bit at the end made me laugh

Comment: quick question do I need to define the variable total as a number also?

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee You can just use `var total;` It doesn't need to be initialized with anything, because you don't **get** it before you **set** it later. Actually, none of the variables need initialized as `0`

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee nope, not in javascript... the variable type will be determined by the value passed to it

Comment: How does this answer work? `document.getElementsByName` returns an array. You can't multiply arrays. And it doesn't matter if they're strings. When you use the `*` operator, the values are coerced into Numbers, so the operation can complete

Comment: Actually, I didn't even notice that... it would be best to put ID's on each thing you want to get values from. And get the values by ID, if using inputs: with jquery you could do `$("#nrOfFruit").val();`... or with regular js, `document.getElementById('nrOfFruit').value`;

Comment: @smerny: And I think `parseInt(..., 10)` would be typically favored over `new Number(...)`.

Comment: @Cory Well, they don't use `new`, which is a little different. And it probably makes sense for that number to be a whole number without decimal, but using `Number()` or the `+` operator will attempt to convert the value to a number in general. `parseFloat` and `parseInt` have intentions to parse them as a float or int.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem was that you weren't using the `fruitOrVeg` variable. Other than that, the retrieval of the elements' values doesn't make sense in your code. Try this:

```
function calc() {
   var total,
       fruitOrVeg,
       nrOfFruit;

   fruitOrVeg = document.getElementsByName("fruitOrVeg")[0].value;
   nrOfFruit = document.getElementsByName("nrOfFruit")[0].value;

   total = fruitOrVeg * nrOfFruit;

   alert(total);
}
```

assuming your HTML is like:

```
<select name="fruitOrVeg">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="text" name="nrOfFruit" />
<br />
<input type="button" id="submit_button" value="Submit" />
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/TNPCh/

So your first problem is that you weren't actually getting the elements' values. You do that by using `.value` to **get** them.

Second problem is that the result of `getElementsByName` is an `HTMLCollection` (an array), so you can't just use `.value` on it. If you're sure there's only one element with this name, just index the array with `[0]` to get the first one found. An easier thing to do is give the elements the `id` attribute and use `document.getElementById` - which returns one and only one element (not an array). I didn't want to assume you were able to do that, so my code still uses `getElementsByName`.

Finally, the multiplication doesn't need any conversion/parsing to a number. The `*` operator automatically coerces the values into numbers so the multiplication can occur. So since they are originally strings, the operation will complete because of this coercion (this is **not** the case with the `+` operator). Of course, if either operand isn't a number in the first place, the multiplication's result will be `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `parseInt` for all the values.You did not have a value for `fruitOrVeg` .Try to declare with a value whatever you want

```
function calc()
{
var total = 0;
var nrOfFruit = 0;

course = Number(document.getElementsByName("fruitOrVeg"));
nrOfFruit = Number(document.getElementsByName("nrOfFruit"));

total = fruitOrVeg * nrOfFruit;

window.alert(total)

}
```

Comment: or `parseFloat` if they are not integer values.

Comment: i think no of fruits means it is int

Comment: you need to declare fruitOrVeg  with a value

Comment: oops that a typo course should read fruitOrVeg. I have it like that in my text editor just changed it by mistake when i was typing the question