# Calculate tax rate with selects using javascript

Tags: javascript, rate

I've been using [code from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084636/calculate-total-onclick-javascript) to create something very similar, the only thing I want to change is the calculation to get a different total result.

In that example they take the first value times the other and then echo out the result.

Taking the first value times the second works very well, but when I try to make the calculation more advanced it all fails.

I want to be able to make the following equation with the selected values:

```
var total = ((firstSelect*secondSelect)-firstSelect*0,68)*300;
alert(total);
```

I've also tried the following and this too fails:

```
var oppa = firstSelect * rate;
var gagnam = secondSelect * 0.68;
var style = oppa - gagnam;
var total = style * 300;

alert(total);
```

Currently my HTML looks like this:

```
<p>Number of sales</p>
 <select name="firstSelect" id="firstSelect" class="DoPricing">
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="150">150</option>
 </select>

 <p>Times rate</p>
 <select name="secondSelect" id="secondSelect" class="DoPricing">
    <option value="0.99">0.99</option>
    <option value="1.15">1.15</option>
    <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
```

and my JS

```
function calc() {
    var total,
    nSales,
    rate;

    var nSales = document.getElementsByName("firstSelect")[0].value;
    var rate = document.getElementsByName("secondSelect")[0].value;

    var oppa = nSales * rate;
    var gagnam = rate * 0.68;
    var style = oppa - gagnam;

    var total = style * 300;

    alert(total);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = calc;
};
```

How would I go about to accomplish this?

Comment: `((firstSelect*secondSelect)-firstSelect*0,68)*300` will always output 20400, because your use of the comma means the value from the outermost parentheses will always be 68. (The `,` should be a `.`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the onclick handler inside the `calc()` function, you should have it outside so it add the event listener on `windows.onload`

```
function calc() {
    var total,
    nSales,
    rate;
    var nSales = document.getElementsByName("firstSelect")[0].value;
    var rate = document.getElementsByName("secondSelect")[0].value;
    var oppa = nSales * rate;
    var gagnam = nSales* 0.68;  //changed to nSales
    var style = oppa - gagnam;
    var total = style * 300;
    alert(total);
};
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = calc;
}
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KmR6N/1/)

Comment: Ah, of course. The results are however still off, so my equation must be wrong somehow. If I take 15 in the first select and 0.99 in the second I get 4253.04, the answer should be 1395. Is there a better way for me to put the equation together?

Comment: @talven, check my updated answer you were missing one `nSales`

Comment: @talven, check my updated answer, the `gagnam` value was wrong calculated, should be `nSales` there

Comment: After your correction i skipped all variables and just did var total = ((nSales*rate)-nSales*0.68)*300; Less is more. Thank you for helping!